# Read lines from a file into a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to automate a large process to save time and effort and I'm probably making it way harder than it needs to be.  What I'm doing so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash
LISTFILE="/tmp/filename"
for FILE in $LISTFILE
    do curl -XDELETE ADDRESS:PORT/VALUE/VALUE/$FILE
done
```

But it's not returning the value for $FILE, instead it's erroring on /tmp and /filename.  What I need it to do is iterate through the file and run the command once for each line and fill in the $FILE value.

Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try with `readline`?

Comment: `while read line; do curl -XDELETE ADDRESS:PORT"/VALUE/VALUE/$line"; done<$LISTFILE`

Answer (score 3):

In that `for`, you are simply doing one iteration where the value of `$FILE` is the value of `$LISTFILE`.

If you are wanting to iterate through the lines in a file, you can use read:

```
while read -r FILE; do
    curl -XDELETE "ADDRESS:PORT/VALUE/VALUE/$FILE"
done < /tmp/filename
```

This assumes that the file has a separate file listed on each line.

Comment: yeah, this is working, but I'm still getting an error, but I think that's from Elasticsearch and not really relevant to this problem.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

This `for` line:

```
for FILE in $LISTFILE
```

Doesn't mean 'for each line in `$LISTFILE`'. It means 'for each item in the variable `$LISTFILE`. Your `$LISTFILE` simply contains the file path, so that's what `$FILE` will be holding.

To get your `for` command to go over 'each line *of the contents of `$LISTFILE`*', you would have to change your code to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
LISTFILE="/tmp/filename"
while read FILE
   do echo $FILE
done < $LISTFILE
```

This uses a `while` loop and uses the command `read`, which reads 'an input' line by line. Our input is the contents of your file, which we specify at the very end (this part: `< $LISTFILE`).

Answer (score 0):

In almost all cases where you use a shell `for` loop to process the lines in a text file, you're better off using `awk` or `cut` or `sed` or `perl` (or any of the other text-processing tools available).  It'll be faster, and easier and with no risk of unwanted side-effects (like setting IFS before using `read`).

For example:

```
awk '{print "curl -XDELETE '\''ADDRESS:PORT/VALUE/VALUE/"$1"'\''"}' \
 /tmp/filename | 
 sh
```

(run it without piping to sh or bash or dash etc first to verify that it produces the correct output)

This does what you want and wraps single quotes around the URL to cater for filenames with spaces, glob wildcards, ampersands, semi-colons etc in them.  Works for all files except those with single-quotes or newlines in the filename.  The latter is unfixable with a newline-separated input file, but the former can be fixed by inserting the following before the `print` statement:

```
gsub(/'\''/,"'"'\\\\''"'");
```

I recently wrote an explanation of what this does here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293818/7696

```
awk '{ gsub(/'\''/,"'"'\\\\''"'");
       print "curl -XDELETE '\''ADDRESS:PORT/VALUE/VALUE/"$1"'\''"}' \
 /tmp/filename | 
 sh
```

If you're absolutely certain there'll be no annoying characters in the filenames, it's even simpler:

```
awk '{ print "curl -XDELETE ADDRESS:PORT/VALUE/VALUE/"$1 }' /tmp/filename | sh
```